# Tweet analysis, Python error when making dictionary for LDA

Tags: python, dictionary, lda, gensim

I've downloaded Tweets about Amsterdam, in UTF-8 using the Twitter API for python.
Now i'm trying to make a dictionary for LDA, using this code (just a part of the code, but this is the part that causes the error):

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open(input_file))
```

which always gives me an error, depending on which txt file I choose as input, either:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

or

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte xxxx in position 175-176: unexpected end of data
```

I expect the reason for this to be characters which are unknown in UTF-8 (some smilies used in Tweets maybe) and after Googling tried to replace the code by:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open(input_file, errors='ignore'))
```

with error message:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open(input_file, errors='ignore'))
TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

or

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open(input_file, 'ignore'))
```

with error message:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open(input_file, 'ignore'))
ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U', not 'ignore'
```

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the data you're reading is utf-8, you can import the codecs module and use `codecs.open()` instead of `open()`

[Reading and Writing Unicode Data](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

Give this a try:

```
import codecs
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in codecs.open(input_file, mode='r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error handling is in the wrong place. You can't open a file while asking to ignore decoding errors; that happens further down the line.

What you should do, is open the file in binary mode (`rb` modifier) and read the lines. They will become `bytes` objects. Then you can decode them and ignore errors:

```
with open('/tmp/myfile', 'rb') as f:
    for linebytes in f.readlines():
        linestring = linebytes.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input file is clearly not UTF-8. There should be documentation explaining what's the actual encoding of these Twitter files; set the encoding accordingly when you open the file.

```
with open(input_file,encoding="whatever Twitter uses") as twitterfile:       
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in twitterfile)
```

This way Python will decode the input to strings without errors, which is clearly superior to ignoring errors and corrupting data.